# Python 3 kwargs insight

Tags: python, methods, arguments, keyword-argument

This has been a source of confusion and frustration for years now. Say you import a particularly poorly documented module and some method that you need to you only has **kwargs for its arguments, how are you supposed to know what keys that method is checking for?

```
def test(**kwargs):
    if 'greeting' in kwargs:
        print(kwargs['greeting'])
```

If i were to call text, how would i know that 'greeting is something the method was looking for?

```
test(greeting='hi)
```

Some simplistic cases the IDE can help out with, but most use cases seem to be out of the IDE's scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `kwargs` as a dictionary. There is no way to tell from the outside what key-value combinations the method will accept (in your case the `test` method is essentially a black box) but this is the point of having documentation. Without kwargs, some function headers would get extremely cluttered.

Comment: So it is up to the author to document the modules, and if they don't we are more or lessed forced to read the code for the method?

Comment: Yep, in my opinion this is why `kwargs` should be avoided in most cases, but makes sense for highly customizable functions in large libraries, i.e. `matplotlib`

Comment: Do you think it might be acceptable to write to the author and request documentation for a method that needlessly uses kwargs? Also, is there some kind of convention specifying a number of keyword arguments before using kwargs?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to ask, and it's fairly common to see something like `def func(key1, key2, **kwargs)` where the first two keys are required but the rest (inside kwargs) are not.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that quite often too. In that case it seems to be more of an error prevention mechanism, no? If you misspell key1, it'll end up in the kwargs.

Comment: Yes, and something else worth noting is that `key1` and `key2` are required whereas variables in kwargs are usually optional

Answer (score 0):

Use documentation!

The [`subprocess`-module's docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) is a good example. If you are using a newer version of python (3.7 or 3.6 with backport), consider using [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) as an alternative to `kwargs`, if it fits your usecase.

Comment: The question already states that the module is poorly documented, and data classes only help if you are *writing* the code (in which case you could also simply write better documentation yourself).

Answer (score 0):

If it's not documented, your only recourse is to read the source.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `**kwargs` argument to a function is used when you don't want to explicitly define the arguments which must be named.

A trivial example:

If a function takes as an argument another function which is undetermined and may have different `kwargs` each time

`def foo(func,**kwargs):
    print(func)
    return func(**kwargs)`

You won't know what the function is explicitly looking for.

You can have in your example

`def foo(greeting=None):`

which shows the function is looking for `greeting` but it can be `None`